# About DataIntigrityViolationException

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am doing the select operations in the database using the spring MVC Jdbc template. In the part of the work, I'm going two input's from the user. But at that time I am getting DataIntegrityViolationException. And the message I am getting in the console like this org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from cyberabadpolice where fir_date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' and current_status='UI']; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

Comment: Please check your question for typo graphical errors and post the structure of your pojo.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding some code snippets and try to rephrase or explain your issue in more details.

Answer (score 1):

my sql statement like:

select EXTRACT(MONTH from TIMESTAMP '[[ddd]]');   //ddd is the input variable  ,Datetime type

if u put the ddd with '2016-12-01 08:40:00', thingworx will give error.